# Contact steam user that is offline

Tags: steam

I have a user in my steam friend list that I need to contact to. But he is offline for few days. There is no contact information specified in his profile. Is there a way to send him an email notification (or any other way), get his email or any other way to contact him?

EDIT: He didn't provide his contact info in his profile. But he must use his email to login to his profile. Maybe I can get his contacts by using Steam API?

EDIT2: OK. I can't get users email if he didn't provide it as a public data in his profile. I think it is good for security reasons.

Comment: You can leave offline messages in Steam. In chat does he show 'Offline' or 'Last online: X Days' ? Some people hide themselves as offline, so an offline message should send through. Otherwise, if he has his info hidden, I do not believe you can gain his email address/ contact details.

Comment: @Aravona I tried to send message to him and left a comment on his profile few days ago. So I believe he is offline for long time (not just hiding from me :) )

Comment: That's good you can post on his profile (not blocked!) he should in theory get your messages next time you log in, however if this is not a RL friend is the matter really so urgent as to find another way to contact him? He could be on holiday / work / school / etc. However if you have mutual Steam friends you could always enquire with them as to his whereabouts and pass on a message.

Comment: just as a note, some people (like myself) are on a 'need to know' basis. And 'gaining' his email address might upset him if he has not given it to you personally.

Comment: You could call them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes, it is possible, but there is no reliable option

**1. Steam offline messages / Steam mobile**

You can still send your Steam friend a message through the known Steam messaging system. As long as he remains offline, the message will be stored and he will be notified when he then logins again. (This is then a green envelop in his Steam software.)

If he uses Steam mobile (liek for Android), he can also use this messaging system on his phone. So maybe you're lucky and he fetches your message on his phone to answer. But TBH I don't see much friends on my list using Steam mobile.

**2. Personal information on his profile**

You can open his Steam community profile - if he has one - to see his personal information which he gives access to. If you're lucky, then maybe he is running a personal website for his own, where you can fetch his Email adress. Otherwise there is no option to mail him but per Steam messaging system.

**3. Steam and Facebook**

[image]

*(I only have this in German localization, but you'll understand.)*

Through Steam community you're also able to connect your Steam profile with your Facebook profile. If your friend did this, you can right-click him in your friends bar and select "Visit Facebook page..." where you get directly redirected to his personal Facebook page. If he did, you're lucky, because once you log in to Facebook, you'll never log out...

You may find a phone number or email adress there, but if he's not out of the 60's, he will know how to use data privacy.

Comment: +1 I agree with these methods, all of them however require the friend to have filled out options, or utilise the android version of Steam. I do not agree with the OP edit of 'gaining' the email address somehow where it has not been freely given.

Comment: Yes, I understand you. Plus, TBH, if he's not a business guy, he will check Facebook more recently than his mail adress. :D

Answer (score 1):

It depends on his steam profile info, if he doesn't have his e-mail or address, etc. listed in his steam profile, then it is impossible to contact him unless you know him personally.

Comment: He didn't provide email as public data in his profile. Can I try to contact his friends from steam so they could deliver my message to him? Will they report me for that? :)

Comment: Well, if you are friends on steam, I think they won't report you for that

Comment: Hi user77997! You shouldn't mark the first given answer as the right one, as other's might not be online 24/7. Arqade is a great community where you can get great answers. Just give your questions a little bit of time. I gave you an answer where I hope you'll have more luck. :)

Comment: @Trollwut yeah. I'm new here and marked this answer as right ASAP cause I understood that I can't get any contact info if it is not public (I is good for security imo). But now I see your answer is more deep. So I mark your answer as correct. Allso I will mark your and this answer as useful when my reputation will be high enough. Sorry JasonSPQR for removing that "accept answer" mark.

Comment: That's no problem. I would suggest you take the tour of this site: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour Thanks for the correct answer.